# Remove space between selected words in a string

Tags: regex, r, string, string-matching

I have a character vector `x` and a `data.frame` `y`as follows.

```
x <- c("Pumpkin Helmet", "Warm  Puppy", "Frisbee Sailing",
       "Warm Puppy Frisbee Sailing", "Good Sport", "Masked Marvel",
       "Spring Dance", "Spring Warm Dance Puppy", "Sock it to Me",
       "Maskedspring Dancemarvel", "warm Puppy", "masked marvel",
       "WARM PUPPY", " Spring Dance", "Warm Puppy Spring  Dance", 
       "Warmspring Dancepuppy")
x   
 [1] "Pumpkin Helmet"             "Warm  Puppy"                "Frisbee Sailing"           
 [4] "Warm Puppy Frisbee Sailing" "Good Sport"                 "Masked Marvel"             
 [7] "Spring Dance"               "Spring Warm Dance Puppy"    "Sock it to Me"             
[10] "Maskedspring Dancemarvel"   "warm Puppy"                 "masked marvel"             
[13] "WARM PUPPY"                 " Spring Dance"              "Warm Puppy Spring  Dance"  
[16] "Warmspring Dancepuppy"  

a <- c("Masked", "Warm", "spring")
b <- c("Marvel", "Puppy", "dance")
y <- data.frame(a,b)

y
       a      b
1 Masked Marvel
2   Warm  Puppy
3 spring  dance
```

I am trying to create a function using `regex` to merge the words in a row in y wherever they exist in `x`.

I have tried the following to get the desired `regex` before trying `apply` with `x` and `y`.

```
gsub("Spring(\\s+)Dance.*", "SpringDance", x)
gsub("spring(\\s+)Dance.*", "SpringDance", x)
gsub("Warm(\\s+)Puppy.*", "WarmPuppy", x)
```

I am still sruggling with `regex` in `R` to get the desired output `out`. What will be the ideal `regex` in this case? It should match only whole words, should ignore case and remove multiple space in between.

```
out <- c("Pumpkin Helmet", "WarmPuppy", "Frisbee Sailing",
         "WarmPuppy Frisbee Sailing", "Good Sport", "MaskedMarvel",
         "SpringDance", "Spring Warm Dance Puppy", "Sock it to Me",
         "Maskedspring Dancemarvel", "warmPuppy", "maskedmarvel",
         "WARMPUPPY", " SpringDance", "WarmPuppy SpringDance", 
         "Warmspring Dancepuppy")

 [1] "Pumpkin Helmet"            "WarmPuppy"                 "Frisbee Sailing"          
 [4] "WarmPuppy Frisbee Sailing" "Good Sport"                "MaskedMarvel"             
 [7] "SpringDance"               "Spring Warm Dance Puppy"   "Sock it to Me"            
[10] "Maskedspring Dancemarvel"  "warmPuppy"                 "maskedmarvel"             
[13] "WARMPUPPY"                 " SpringDance"              "WarmPuppy SpringDance"    
[16] "Warmspring Dancepuppy"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
> gsub("(?i)(?<=^Spring|^warm|^masked)\\s+(?=Dance|puppy|marvel)\\b|\\b(?<=Spring|warm|masked)\\s+(?=Dance$|puppy$|marvel$)", "", x, perl=T)
 [1] "Pumpkin Helmet"            "WarmPuppy"                 "Frisbee Sailing"          
 [4] "WarmPuppy Frisbee Sailing" "Good Sport"                "MaskedMarvel"             
 [7] "SpringDance"               "Spring Warm Dance Puppy"   "Sock it to Me"            
[10] "Maskedspring Dancemarvel"  "warmPuppy"                 "maskedmarvel"             
[13] "WARMPUPPY"                 " SpringDance"              "WarmPuppy SpringDance"    
[16] "Warmspring Dancepuppy"
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` case insensitive modifier helps to turn on the case insensitive mode.
- `(?<=^Spring|^warm|^masked)` Looks after to the string `spring` or `warm` or `masked` which are at the start.
- `\\s+`, if yes then match the following one or more spaces.
- `(?=Dance|puppy|marvel)\\b` And also check whether the spaces are followed by `Dance` or - `puppy` or `marvel`. If yes, then retain the matches otherwise loose those matched spaces.
- `|` Logical OR operator.
- `\b` Word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `$` End of the line anchor.

Comment: Yup. The last one was the one that I wanted. The explanation is great at understanding the regex.